# Amazon EC2: Host does not exist

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one running instance on my EC2 account. Unfortunately I cannot connect to this machine.
I have tried directly in the browser with this Java application as well as with Putty. In both  I have the same result: Host does not exist.

What may be the possible cause of this error?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you have opened port 22 for public internet ( or your public ID) in the security group.

Check for the correct public DNS name if you have stopped the instance and restarted again. Public DNS names are subject to change if you haven't attached any Elastic IP

Comment: I have port number 22 opened, also my public DNS name is correct as well as my security key.